# htaccess config to improve increase OpenCart 2.3.0.2 pagespeed and redirect to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart2.x, pagespeed

How can I config my htaccess file? I need to increase page speed and redirect to https://www. version of website.

- Opencart  2.3.0.2, php 7.3
- SSL already installed and turned on.
- Images already compressed.

Config:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip

Header unset ETag
FileETag None

<FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2100 00:00:00 GMT"
    Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# RSS feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I found this in the documentation:

> Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
>   Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.  If you
>   get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following
>   settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.
>
> 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it: 
>      php_flag register_globals off
> 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:  php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
> 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try  php_value upload_max_filesize
>      999M
> 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all
>      fields php_value post_max_size 999M
> 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not
>      saving all fields php_value max_execution_time 200
> 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are
>      not saving all fields php_value max_input_time 200
> 7. disable open_basedir limitations php_admin_value open_basedir none

What can I do to make my site more secure?

Answer (score 1):

### Redirect to https://www

You can copy below code and paste you htaccess file

```
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip

    Header unset ETag
    FileETag None

    <FilesMatch "(?i)^.*\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Expires "Fri, 21 Dec 2100 00:00:00 GMT"
        Header set Cache-Control "public, no-transform"
    </FilesMatch>

    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive on

    # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
      ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
      ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Your document html
      ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # Data
      ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

    # RSS feed
      ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

    # Media: images, video, audio
      ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

    # HTC files  (css3pie)
      ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

    # Webfonts
      ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
      ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

    # CSS and JavaScript
      ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"

      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    # 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

    # 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

    # For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

    Options +FollowSymlinks

    # Prevent Directoy listing
    Options -Indexes

    # Prevent Direct Access to files
    <FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

    # SEO URL Settings
    RewriteEngine On
    # If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
    RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

    # https:// to https://www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

### Increase Website Speed / Performance

I will suggest you use this really good extension for the boost your OpenCart website. I always used it and its reviews also appreciate it.

[Download the extension here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=36373&filter_category_id=20&filter_license=0)